# Spring boot app not showing whitelable error page when built using -xdebug mode

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, pgadmin

I am working on spring boot maven project on intellijidea , I was building project by running command mvn spring-boot:run -P localdev. it was properly building and showing white label error page. but now when I am building project with debug mode

```
<configuration>
<jvmArguments>
    -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005
</jvmArguments>
</configuration>
```

Then it is building and showing spring icon , but local host is not showing white label error page
and simply showing refused to connect.

I got this bad behavior when I hit an api in debug mode and before the controller return response line I executed a query in pgadmin for some testing purpose .

what can be done , i think issue is related to jdbc connection opened in pgadmin as well as app was trying to get the jdbc connection at same time

Comment: Add more details including full Maven configuration and how exactly you launch it in Run and Debug modes.

Comment: @Andrey  Thank you for responding to my question but fortunately i got the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I got the Solution . I had marked an break point at a method while debugging.
And Method breakpoints may dramatically slow down debugging , thats why i was not getting the white label error page .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).